# How to connect Superset with AWS athena?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sqlalchemy, amazon-athena

Has anyone tried connecting superset to AWS athena ?

I was able to connect to redshift by using SQLAlchemy URI:
postgresql://username:password@xxxx.redshift.amazonaws.com:port/dbname

but I am having hard time connecting to AWS athena. AWS has JDBC driver (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-with-jdbc.html) but I can't figure out how to use it with superset. Any example ?

Answer (score 7):

In case someone else would come here:

`awsathena+jdbc://username:password@xxxx.redshift.amazonaws.com:port/dbname`

This is from the [superset documentation](https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html#database-dependencies).

Answer (score 3):

We tried installing superset with PyAthena JDBC & REST. Our experience with PyAthena (REST) is far better than PyAthenaJDBC, would recommend to use same in production.

Install PyAthena (pure python library, java is not needed)

```
pip install "PyAthena>1.2.0"
```

Access database by creating connection url

```
awsathena+rest://{aws_access_key_id}:{aws_secret_access_key}@athena.{region_name}.amazonaws.com/{schema_name}?s3_staging_dir={s3_staging_dir}&...
```

I found this [article](https://medium.com/@nileshxbhosale/apache-superset-a-cost-effective-alternative-to-quick-sight-for-data-lake-668868fe51c7), a good guide on deploying superset.

Comment: Where should I be writing the ```pip install``` command? I have installed Superset on an EC2 instance and am accesing it via port

Comment: pip - package manager for python. You should write that in the terminal in your EC2 instance

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this github PR](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/pull/2538/files)
You'll want to install PyAthenaJDBC package into pip.  The driver that you are referring to is a Java driver, which is great, but Superset is largely a Python application, so it'll need a python driver to connect/interact with Athena.

The above answer is correct, but you'll want to install that package to ensure that you actually can connect to athena.

Answer (score 0):

You must define a property s3_staging_dir when you connect to Athena's Driver.

Example: s3_staging_dir=s3://your_bucket

Answer (score 0):

### I got it to work using: PyAthenaJDBC (python 3.6.7) with these steps:

1) Make sure you have the PyAthenaJDBC pkg. installed:

```
pip install "PyAthenaJDBC>1.0.9"
```

2) Restart superset

3) Download the JDBC driver: from [aws driver download](https://pypi.org/project/PyAthenaJDBC/) I used the  AthenaJDBC41-2.0.6.jar version

- Example driver download url, **Note**: I saved my driver in /drivers/

  wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/athena-downloads/drivers/JDBC/SimbaAthenaJDBC_2.0.6/AthenaJDBC41_2.0.6.jar

4) Add the data-source to superset:

```
awsathena+jdbc://AWS_KEY:AWS_SECRET@athena.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mydb?s3_staging_dir=s3://path/to/my/data/&driver_path=/drivers/AthenaJDBC41_2.0.6.jar
```

**Note:** If superset is running on ECS / EC2 you can assign an IAM role, and remove the AWS KEY/SECRET from the URI, Example raw connection URI below:

```
awsathena+jdbc://{aws_key}:{aws_secret}@athena.{region_name}.amazonaws.com/{schema_name}?s3_staging_dir={s3_staging_dir}&driver_path={driver_path}
```

Much more info [here](https://pypi.org/project/PyAthenaJDBC/):

Comment: Hi, If I'm using an EC2 instance, where would I save the Driver?

Answer (score 0):

**Official guidance from Superset:**

https://superset.apache.org/docs/databases/athena

`awsathena+rest://{aws_access_key_id}:{aws_secret_access_key}@athena.{region_name}.amazonaws.com/{schema_name}?s3_staging_dir={s3_staging_dir}&...`

**You need to have some tweaks by yourself. This worked for me after many hours of reading posts on 2021-12-12:**

`awsathena+rest://{secret id}:{secret access key}@athena.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/test?s3_staging_dir=s3://{your bucket where Athena query result is stored}/test/&work_group=primary`

**Note that in my example:**

`"schema_name = test":` You must see a database named "test" under Athena \ Query Editor \ Database at this point. It is created in Glue Console \ Data Catalog \ Database with a crawler or manual.

`s3://{your bucket}/{path if needed}/test:` you need to go to Athena \ Workgroups, select a workgroup and check the setting if it turned on the "Query result location" or not. In my case, the name of the workgroup is "primary", the query result of the "test" database will be stored in s3://{your bucket where Athena query result is stored}/test/

**Make sure you have installed these under Python Virtual Environment**:

```
pip install "PyAthenaJDBC>1.0.9"

pip install "PyAthena>1.2.0"
```

**See how to create Superset under Python Env:**

https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-from-scratch

**Security Group:**

(I got this instruction from here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzuPQPRcT-0)

I build Superset on the EC2 Instance. Therefore, you need to check out the security group setting. Because it relates to EC2 service, Athena service, and the website which Superset is running in UI.

In my case, I have turned on all these settings to make sure it can run the first time. Then you can narrow down the setting later.

Custom TCP - TCP - 8088 - ::/0 ; 0.0.0.0/0

HTTP - TCP - 80 - ::/0 ; 0.0.0.0/0

SSH - TCP - 22 - ::/0 ; 0.0.0.0/0

Custom ICMP - IPv4 - Echo Request - N/A - 0.0.0.0/0

All ICMP - IPv6 - IPv6 ICMP - All - ::/0

All ICMP - IPv6 - IPv6 ICMP - All - 0.0.0.0/0

Answer (score 0):

After lot of hustle managed to create connection string which works, note that all key & s3 path needs to be encoded, below format works for me

```
awsathena+rest://{encoded aws_access_key_id}:{encoded aws_secret_access_key}@athena.{region_name}.amazonaws.com:443/{schema_name}?s3_staging_dir={encoded s3_staging_dir}
```

You can use below code to generate connection string, save it to file & run

```
from urllib.parse import quote_plus

conn_str = "awsathena+rest://{aws_access_key_id}:{aws_secret_access_key}@athena.{region_name}.amazonaws.com:443/"\
       "{schema_name}?s3_staging_dir={s3_staging_dir}"
               
print(conn_str.format(
      aws_access_key_id=quote_plus("{aws_access_key_id}"),
      aws_secret_access_key=quote_plus("{aws_secret_access_key}"),
      region_name="{region_name}",
      schema_name="{schema_name}",
      s3_staging_dir=quote_plus("{s3_staging_dir}")))
```